# plot a pie chart from json data in d3

Tags: json, d3.js, charts

here is the geojson file

```
     {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "profit": 326,
            "npa": 174.000000
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "profit": 1762,
            "npa": 1683.000000
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to plot a pie chart from the geojson code. i want the pie chart based on the value "profit". Thanks in advance

fiddle link which i tried click here for fiddle – https://jsfiddle.net/venkatkiranpolamuri/92hn5bfb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to understand how to retrieve data from a nested JSON structure using d3.

The simplest approach is to use your browser's console (F12 in Chrome) and print out the data you're trying to access. Where you were trying to set the `value` for the pie layout you had

```
return d.profit
```

However, by adding a `console.log(d.profit)` line you can see that this is an undefined value.

In fact `profit` is nested in a `properties` level, and you need to step into this level first:

```
.value(function (d) {
    console.log(d)
    // Changed the next line from d.profit
    return d.properties.profit;
}
```

Likewise when getting `value` to set the arc color and text value, you should use:

```
d.value
```

rather than

```
d.data.profit
```

to return the value you want from the `pie(data)` structure.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/henbox/ed3tukwx/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.... this is what i exactly needed.

Comment: Sir, how to give an local geojson file as an input and get the same result???

Comment: Base your code on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235, but use `d3.json` in place of `d3.csv`. See "Reading JSON Files" section on http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html for a good explanation.

Comment: Also, if the answer above works for you, can you mark it as accepted? Thanks!